# book about self replicating crablike robots who invade North America

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, books

I am looking for a book I got from Fictionwise about self replicating crablike robots who invade North America.   A NASA scientist has been working on a crab like rover for mars and uses it to battle the aliens.   A father and son are camping when they discover the nest for the robots

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You tagged this books and short-stories; which is it?

Answer (score 3):

This has some similarities to Greg Bear's [*The Forge of God*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forge_of_God).

Earth is being attacked by self-replicating machines which were sent out by a civilisation to destroy all other sentient life.

Another set of machines also arrives, in the form of small spider-like robots - although their intention is to preserve what they can, they are initially thought to be invaders. There is a scene of them being discovered by the main character and his son camping, although I don't think there was anything about battling them using a Mars rover.